# I'm trying to save scraped data to a CSV file with Python but get the a TypeError

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to save `scraped data` to a csv file. However, I get this following error

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.
I think the error is coming from this piece of code.

```
csv_writer.writerow(str(row['url']), str(row['img']), str(row['text']))
```

Following is the entire code..

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
page_url = 'https://alansimpson.me/python/scrape_sample.html'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4514.131 Safari/537.36'}
rawpage = requests.get(page_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rawpage.content, 'html5lib')
content = soup.article
link_list = []
for link in content.find_all('a'):
    try:
        url = link.get('href')
        img = link.get('src')
        text = link.span.text
        link_list.append([{'url':url, 'img':img, 'text':text}])
    except AttributeError:
        pass
with open('links.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_out:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    csv_writer.writerow(['url', 'img', 'text'])
for row in link_list:
    csv_writer.writerow(str(row['url']), str(row['img']), str(row['text']))
print('All done')
```

Please Note: The following piece of code creates a file and write's the row

```
with open('links.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_out:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    csv_writer.writerow(['url', 'img', 'text'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### UPDATE

Using the `csv.DictWriter()`:

```
with open('links.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_out:
    i = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, fieldnames = set().union(*(d.keys() for d in link_list)))
    i.writeheader()
    i.writerows(link_list)
```

*You could use `set().union(*(d.keys() for d in link_list))` to fetch a list of keys from your `dicts` or simply pass `['url', 'img', 'text']` as `fieldnames`*

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
page_url = 'https://alansimpson.me/python/scrape_sample.html'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4514.131 Safari/537.36'}
rawpage = requests.get(page_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rawpage.content, 'html5lib')
content = soup.article
link_list = []
for link in content.find_all('a'):
    try:
        url = link.get('href')
        img = link.img.get('src')
        text = link.span.text
        link_list.append({'url':url, 'img':img, 'text':text})
    except AttributeError:
        pass
with open('links.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_out:
    i = csv.DictWriter(csv_out, fieldnames = set().union(*(d.keys() for d in link_list)))
    i.writeheader()
    i.writerows(link_list)
print('All done')
```

---

###### Alternativ approaches:

Store your data simply as `dict` and not as `list` with `dict` in `list`:

```
link_list.append({'url':url, 'img':img, 'text':text})
```

and write it like:

```
csv_writer.writerow([row['url'], row['img'], row['text']])
```

Or even simpler save it directly as `list`:

```
link_list.append([url,img,text])
```

and write it as list:

```
csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
page_url = 'https://alansimpson.me/python/scrape_sample.html'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4514.131 Safari/537.36'}
rawpage = requests.get(page_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rawpage.content, 'html5lib')
content = soup.article
link_list = []
for link in content.find_all('a'):
    try:
        url = link.get('href')
        img = link.img.get('src')
        text = link.span.text
        link_list.append({'url':url, 'img':img, 'text':text})
    except AttributeError:
        pass
with open('links.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csv_out:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    csv_writer.writerow(['url', 'img', 'text'])
    for row in link_list:
        csv_writer.writerow([row['url'], row['img'], row['text']])
print('All done')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bug Fix :**
replace this line `img = link.get('src')` to `img = link.img.get('src')`

**Updated Code :**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page_url = 'https://alansimpson.me/python/scrape_sample.html'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4514.131 Safari/537.36'}
rawpage = requests.get(page_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rawpage.content, 'html5lib')
content = soup.article
link_list = []
for link in content.find_all('a'):
    try:
        url = link.get('href')
        img = link.img.get('src')
        text = link.span.text
        link_list.append({
          'url':url,
          'img':img,
          'text':text,

        })
    except AttributeError:
        pass

df = pd.DataFrame(link_list)
print(df)
```