# How to separate part of the string where it is all upper case?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below is a sample dataset in html:

```html
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of IR</h4><p>Diane PHILIPS</p></div>,
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of Finance</h4><p>Nancy LOPEZ</p></div>,
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of HR</h4><p>George SANTOZ</p></div>,
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of </h4><p>KUMBARO FURXHI Mirela</p></div>
```

I utilized BeautifulSoup to extract the data and pipe delimited h4 and p.

```
for leader_list in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'leader-info'}):
print(leader_list.get_text(strip=True, separator='|'))
```

However, I want to separate the given name and the surname within the `p` tag. The surname is in all caps and can be in the beginning or at the end of the string. It can also be multiple words with space in between. How would I go about transforming the output into the following?

```
Director of IR|Diane|PHILIPS
Director of Finance|Nancy|LOPEZ
Director of HR|George|SANTOZ
Director of HR|KUMBARO FURXHI|Mirela
```

Comment: Before you try this: what generates that content, and can you fix _that_ to properly mark up first and last names? (e.g. using `<span class="first name">Diane</span><span class="last name">Philips</span>` or the like. And yes, the spaces in those class attribute at intentional. You describe them as `span.first.name { ... }` on the CSS side).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the content is part of a public website. I have no way of modifying the data format other than to extract it and manipulate it on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

---

You could check if a string `.isupper()` and in addition there is `.capitalize()` to "normalize" the `last_name`, if needed:

```
'last_name':' '.join([s.capitalize() for s in e.p.text.split() if s.isupper()])
```

*I would recommend to use a more structured way to store your results instead of just printing.*

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of IR</h4><p>Diane PHILIPS</p></div>,
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of Finance</h4><p>Nancy LOPEZ</p></div>,
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of HR</h4><p>George SANTOZ</p></div>,
<div class="leader-info"><h4>Director of </h4><p>KUMBARO FURXHI Mirela</p></div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []

for e in soup.select('.leader-info'):
   d = {
      'title':e.h4.text,
      'first_name':' '.join([s for s in e.p.text.split() if not s.isupper()]),
      'last_name':' '.join([s.capitalize() for s in e.p.text.split() if s.isupper()])
   }
   data.append(d)
   print('|'.join(d.values()))

data
```

###### Output

Print:

```
Director of IR|Diane|Philips
Director of Finance|Nancy|Lopez
Director of HR|George|Santoz
Director of |Mirela|Kumbaro Furxhi
```

data:

```
[{'title': 'Director of IR', 'first_name': 'Diane', 'last_name': 'Philips'},
 {'title': 'Director of Finance', 'first_name': 'Nancy', 'last_name': 'Lopez'},
 {'title': 'Director of HR', 'first_name': 'George', 'last_name': 'Santoz'},
 {'title': 'Director of ',
  'first_name': 'Mirela',
  'last_name': 'Kumbaro Furxhi'}]
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71840916/14460824 answer that deals with the topic.